# Getting this exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/ListenerList

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I was trying to run an auto complete code and I have added swt and jface jar to build path.

I am not sure as to which plugin is missing or to be added in eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/ListenerList
at org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.ContentProposalAdapter.<init>(ContentProposalAdapter.java:1202)
at AutoCompleteComboTextControls.enableContentProposal(AutoCompleteComboTextControls.java:83)
at AutoCompleteComboTextControls.main(AutoCompleteComboTextControls.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.ListenerList
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Did you set a proper target plattform?

Comment: `ContentProposalAdapter` seems to have a dependency on the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin which in turn depends on a number of other Eclipse plugins. So it is probably only usable in an Eclipse plugin and not in a SWT/JFace program.

Comment: yes @greg I was able to fix it thanks